# $_POST is not what I expect it to be

Tags: php, jquery

I want to write a very simple web page. There is only one button which triggers a POST method which is called on a PHP file. But the $_POST variable in the PHP file remains empty when the button is clicked.
Here are my codes:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="mypost();">POST</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
function mypost(){
  $.post("test.php","Hello World!");
}
```

test.php:

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST);
```

Comment: You need to give your parameter a `name`. Like: `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`. Note that this ignores the return results.

Comment: That's an odd use of `$.post()`.  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Is the AJAX HTTP request made?  What data does it contain?  What is the server's response?  (That is, where are you observing this output?)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I did as you said. But the problem remains. Array() is what I get.

Comment: How exactly are you grabbing the output? Do you by any chance have the test.php file open in a second tab/window and just expect the output to magically appear there?

Comment: @ArSeN Yes, I have the test.php file open in a second tab and after clicking the button I refresh it and I expect the output to appear there.

Comment: Then you have a misunderstanding of the basic concepts of how HTTP and request flows work. You might wanna read up on it: https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande91si/www-spr04/readings/week1/InternetWhitepaper.htm

Answer (score 2):

The data parameter to `$.post` needs to be parameter names and values, but you didn't give a name to the value.

Try

```
function mypost(){
  $.post("test.php",{param: "Hello World!"});
}
```

Then you'll get the associative array

```
Array(param => "Hello World!")
```

Comment: I did as you suggested. But still what I get is: Array()

Comment: I don't know why, I'm certain this should work.

Comment: @Mesigooly I would suggest making a normal form that submits the same information, or attempt to replicate the request in a REST Client.  As this answer should work.